# Java: serialize TreeModel, TableModel to JSON, and vice versa?

Tags: java, json, tablemodel, treemodel

On the client side, a user specified input creates a unique TreeModel and TableModel.

This needs to be serialized to JSON for storage on MongoDB (stores JSON document directly).

The JSON needs to be parsed back into a TreeModel or TableModel which will be rendered again on the client side software.

Any library or existing codes which can faciliate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeModel and TableModel are just interfaces without data therefore they cant be serialized. However when you talk about TreeModel implementation e.g. DefaultTreeModel you can serialize it to Json using [Jackson POJO data binding](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Full_Data_Binding_.28POJO.29_Example)

Answer (score 1):

Jackson can do so in [5 minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the model's data and use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to generate the json. I.e.:

```
public static JsonNode getJsonNodeFromModel(DefaultTableModel model) {
    ArrayNode jsonArray = MAPPER.createArrayNode();

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        ObjectNode jsonNode = MAPPER.createObjectNode();

        String name = (String) model.getValueAt(i, 0);
        String command = ((String) model.getValueAt(i, 1)).replace("\\", "\\\\");

        jsonNode.put(model.getColumnName(0), name);
        jsonNode.put(model.getColumnName(1), command);

        jsonArray.add(jsonNode);
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
    Object[] columnNames = new Object[]{"Name", "Shell Command"};
    Object[][] data = {
        {"Open jsonlint.com", "open http://jsonlint.com"},
        {"Open Escape/UnEscape Tool", "open http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html"}
    };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    JsonNode jsonNode = CommandHelper.getJsonNodeFromModel(model);

    assertEquals("Open jsonlint.com", jsonNode.get(0).get("Name").asText());
    assertEquals("open http://jsonlint.com", jsonNode.get(0).get("Shell Command").asText());
    assertEquals("Open Escape/UnEscape Tool", jsonNode.get(1).get("Name").asText());
    assertEquals("open http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html", jsonNode.get(1).get("Shell Command").asText());
}
```